# Laravel 9 Vue js 3 multipart form, console showing full html, not only the retrieved data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, axios

I'm using a multipart form to send texts and image to database,
The data have been successfully sent to the database, but why in the console it is showing the data infull html ? not only the data that has been retrieved ?

this is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="gabungPage">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="backgroundGabung" id="hrefGabung">
                <div class="tulisanGabung p-5">
                    <div class="cardGabung">
                        
                        <p class="teksGabung">Tingkatkan bisnismu sekarang dengan bergabung menjadi mitra JAI'</p>
                      
                        <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nama">Nama</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="nama"
                              v-model="formulirs.nama"
                              class="form-control"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="alamat">Alamat</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="alamat"
                              v-model="formulirs.alamat"
                              class="form-control"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="email"
                              v-model="formulirs.email"
                              class="form-control"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nomor">nomor</label>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="nomor"
                              v-model="formulirs.nomor"
                              class="form-control"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">Image</label>
                            <input
                              type="file"
                              id="image"
                              ref="imageInput"
                              @change="uploadImage"
                            />
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tesss">
                    <h1> <span class="tulisKiri1">Gabung jadi</span> <br> <span class="tulisKiri2">mitra jahit</span></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formulirs: {
        nama: '',
        alamat: '',
        nomor: '',
        email: '',
        image: null,
      },
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    uploadImage() {
      this.formulirs.image = this.$refs.imageInput.files[0];
    },
    async submitForm() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('nama', this.formulirs.nama);
        formData.append('alamat', this.formulirs.alamat);
        formData.append('email', this.formulirs.email);
        formData.append('nomor', this.formulirs.nomor);
        formData.append('image', this.formulirs.image);

        axios.post('/api/submit-form', formData).then(
              response => {
                  console.log(response);
                  this.$toast.success(`Data berhasil dikirim`,{
                    position: "bottom",
                  });
              }
          ). catch(error => {
              console.log('error');
              this.$toast.error(`Terjadi kegagalan`,{
                    position: "bottom",
                  });
          })
      },
  },
};
</script>
```

the routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/api/submit-form', [FormulirsController::class, 'store']);
```

the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'nama' => 'required',
            'alamat' => 'required',
            'nomor' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'image' => 'required|image',
        ]);

        $formulir = new Formulirs;
        $formulir->nama = $validatedData['nama'];
        $formulir->alamat = $validatedData['alamat'];
        $formulir->nomor = $validatedData['nomor'];
        $formulir->email = $validatedData['email'];

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->storeAs('public/images', $imageName);
        $formulir->image = $imageName;

        $formulir->save();

        return back()->with('success', 'Data berhasil dikirim');
    }
```

I have tried to show the data only by changing to

```
console.log(response.data)
```

But it got worse, it only shows full html page in the console, what should I do so that it doesn't display the full html page?

Answer (score 0):

You're making an `axios request` and returning `back` method. This is used for redirecting in a monolitic app. I recommend you return a `JSON response` in your controller. Something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'nama' => 'required',
        'alamat' => 'required',
        'nomor' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'image' => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $formulir = new Formulirs;
    $formulir->nama = $validatedData['nama'];
    $formulir->alamat = $validatedData['alamat'];
    $formulir->nomor = $validatedData['nomor'];
    $formulir->email = $validatedData['email'];

    $image = $request->file('image');
    $imageName = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->storeAs('public/images', $imageName);
    $formulir->image = $imageName;

    $formulir->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Data berhasil dikirim'); // this is yours
    return response()->json('Data berhasil dikirim'); // 200 status code is the second param by default. You can change for whatever you want.
}
```